# Systeme-package not printing an equation system with unknown multipliers

Tags: systeme

I tried to use the "systeme"-package while working with some systems of equations. It worked well enough as long as I was working with numbers and only a single set of variables (x_1 -> x_4), but as soon as I tried to work with formal multiplies (a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}, etc.) it told me "L'indice n'est pas un nombre entier !." ("the index is not a number entry" far as I can figure).

I can't imagine that such a system couldn't handle constants so there has to be a way around this but I can't figure it out nor find any other posts on the problem, which is why I'm coming to you for help. Here's what I had that caused the issue:

```
\systeme{
    a_{11} x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 = b_1,
    a_{22} x_2 + a_{23}x_3 = b_2,
    a_{33} x_3 = b_3}
```

I tried doing it a few different ways including switching x_1 - x_3 for x, y and z and using \system[xyz] with the same code otherwise but it refused to budge. I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong and I can't find a good documentation for \systeme (I found out about the whole package here on StackExchange actually while looking for a way to align a linear system of equations efficiently).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! "Un nombre entier" is French for "an integer", I would assume.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: You assume correctly :-)

Comment: Thanks! I've studied French and I can speak it to a degree, but my math French is kinda awful ^^' Now that you say it, it's kinda obvious but I just couldn't make the connection (I'm not a native English speaker either and in my native language "integer" is "kokonaisluku" for "whole number", so the terms related to integrity are a bit less natural to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use substitutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\syssubstitute{A{a_{11}}B{a_{12}}C{a_{13}}D{a_{22}}E{a_{23}}F{a_{33}}}
\systeme{
  A x_1 + B x_2 + C x_3 = b_1,
  D x_2 + E x_3 = b_2,
  F x_3 = b_3
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers! I knew I was missing something. Do you, by chance, happen to know of any documentation for this package that would explain this sort of stuff in detail?

Comment: @JarnoPorkka [`texdoc systeme`](https://texdoc.org/serve/systeme/0) In French, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just have to make do - using my French will do me good anyways.